# Variables de sesion spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hola estoy comenzando con spring boot, tengo una aplicación con un login donde con el username de un empleado voy a buscar el ID de oficina, el que necesito que se mantenga durante toda la sesion del usuario. Ya que según ese ID de oficina de cargaran las diferentes opciones y datos de las distintas vistas.
Por lo que quisiera saber como mantener el valor de una variable y pasarla entre controladores, algo asi como el equivalente de `$_SESSION['variable']` en php.

Alguna idea?
gracias

Comment: Dónde está el código en el que creas la sesión a partir del login? Incluirlo en la pregunta es necesario

Comment: usa HttpServletRequest getSession() getParameter() or getAttributes algo asi?